# How do I fix my conversion from serialized C# date to js date, as the js date is out by a day or the timezone

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timezone

I found the answer some minutes after posting this.

Scenario: I serialize a date from a C# ControllerAction and store that in a js variable,
which I then convert to a js date, via toISOString, but the js date is then the previous day. I think the issue is the dateTimeOffset, but I don't know how to resolve it.
I have tried getting the local TimeZoneOffset and adding that to the js date, but without success.
The end goal is to return that same date to C# controller in the format "yyyy/mm/dd".

```
function getFormattedDate(inDate)
{
    console.log("inDate=" + inDate);  //  =  /Date(1564610400000)/

    var d = new Date()
    var tzDifference  = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    console.log("datetimeOffset=" + tzDifference );  // =-120

    var date = new Date(parseInt(inDate.substr(6)));
    // CORRECT date=Thu Aug 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
    var res = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");  

    // res=20190731  (C# has it as 2019/08/01 00:00:00) so res should be 20190801.

    var yr = res.substr(0, 4);
    var mth = res.substr(4, 2);
    var dy = res.substr(6, 2);
    var dateFormatted = yr + '/' + mth + '/' + dy;

    return dateFormatted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
    var date = new Date(parseInt(inDate.substr(6)));
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('/');
```